# RequiresNew transaction after rolling back still affect entity

Tags: spring-boot, transactions, rollback, propagation

Context: spring boot 2.7.0 , @EnableTransactionManagement at main application class

Assumption: the unchecked exception should roll back the internal transaction, but since it is caught, it will not affect the external transaction.

Solution used:

```
@Service
class ExternalService {
  final InnerService innerService;

  @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
  public User requiredRequired(User user) {
    user = userRepository.save(user);
    try {
      innerService.doRequired(user);
    } catch (RuntimeException e) { 
    // error handling
    }
    return user;
  }
}

@Service
public class InnerService {
  @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
  
  public void doRequiresNew(User user) {
    affectUser(user);
    // if condition then:
    throw new RuntimeException("Rollback this 'doRequiresNew' transaction!");
    }

    private void affectUser(User user) {
    // change something in User .ex:
    user.setFirstName(user.getFirstName() + "_affected!");
  }
}
```

Input:
`User(firstName=Lolek, lastName=Bolek)`

Result in database:
`User(id=1, createdAt=2023-11-05T17:03:23.324309Z, firstName=Lolek_affected!, lastName=Bolek)`

Question: why results of the new transaction are still persisted?

PS. It works only if method of `InnerService` has `@Transactional (propagation = Propagation.NESTED)` annotation